# Assign unique numbers to File during runtime

Tags: c, linux

I want to assign unique file numbers to files during run time.

1. Creating hash for the file name is not an option for me as I do not want any collisions.
2. One good option is create running numbers for all files. But I do not have access to source file to walk the directory in place where I am running my binary.

So I need some option that can extract file name from the binary (Say using symbol table similar to GDB). I am not sure how to do that. Any help is appriciated

Comment: use date and time, I doubt you will have duplicates :)

Comment: You still need a hash, just not one entirely dependent on the name

Comment: What is a file number for you, and how do you want them unique? Do you know about [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and [file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)? Looks like your question might make no sense.

Comment: Could you make an example of what in your case is a unique file numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the inode number (st_ino) from the file itself -- you get that from using fstat (http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat).

The inode number is how the file system is keeping track of the files, and they are unique for the given file system -- hence as long as the files are not located on different files systems (different mount points) the inode number is unique.

This include if there are multiple links to the same file, if that worries you as well.

Comment: If there are multiple _hard_ links, they will have the same inode. `touch a; ln a b; ls -i a b` to prove it.

Comment: Yes -- multiple links (hard or soft) lead to the same file -- they are the same file, which is the point -- so they should have the same id number if the OPs question is understood correctly.

Comment: I thought you were intending to state that multiple links had different inodes. Multiple _soft_ links _do_ have different inodes though. `touch a; ln -s a b; ln -s a c; ls -i` shows this. If that's a concern, lstat() addresses it.

Comment: I was specific in stating that he should use _fstat_ -- with fstat you provide a fd which means that you have opened the file, and you will get the inode number of the actual file.  Your test is invalid because you get the inode number of the symlink and not the actual file.  try to do a 'ls -iH' and you will see that the inode of the actual file (not the symlink name) is the same regardless of whether you use hard or soft links. (A common mistake is to think of the name of the file as the file itself -- you can have files without names, and the name is just a link to the file.)

Comment: Your tone seems to suggest you've been offended, and so if you are upset with what I've said, I apologize. I am not arguing with you, but your tone suggests you're agreeing violently with me.

Comment: Apologies -- that was not the intention -- reading it back I can see it come across that way.